# Vasiliev equations Cartan gauge invariance - arXiv:1208.3880

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, string-theory, quantum-gravity, gauge-invariance

I am going through https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.3880  and I am somehow struggling to show that the Vasiliev field equation (2.24)
\begin{equation}
d_{x}W + W *W = 0
\end{equation}
is invariant under the following transformation (2.23)
\begin{equation}
\delta W = d \epsilon + \left[ W, \epsilon \right]_{*}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
\epsilon = \frac{1}{4i}\Lambda^{\alpha\beta}M^{(0)}_{\alpha\beta} \qquad and \qquad M^{(0)}_{\alpha\beta} = y_{\alpha}y_{\beta}- z_{\alpha}z_{\beta}
\end{equation}
I tried to approach in a very simple way
\begin{equation}
d_{x}(\delta W) + (\delta W) * (\delta W) = d_{x}(d \epsilon + \left[ W, \epsilon \right]_{*}) + (d \epsilon + \left[ W, \epsilon \right]_{*}) * (d \epsilon + \left[ W, \epsilon \right]_{*})
\end{equation}
But the star products quickly get messy, I had hoped some terms will collapse to zero
\begin{equation}
 d_{x}(d \epsilon + \left[ W, \epsilon \right]_{*}) = d_{x}(d\epsilon) + d_{x}(W*\epsilon - \epsilon * W) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(d \epsilon + \left[ W, \epsilon \right]_{*}) * (d \epsilon + \left[ W, \epsilon \right]_{*}) = d\epsilon * d\epsilon + d\epsilon * \left[ W, \epsilon \right]_{*} + \left[ W, \epsilon \right]_{*} * d\epsilon + \left[ W, \epsilon \right]_{*} * \left[ W, \epsilon \right]_{*}
\end{equation}
If what I have thus far is correct, then my issue might be in evaluating the star products

\begin{align}
W *\epsilon &= W \left[1 + \epsilon^{\alpha\beta}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{\alpha}}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z^{\alpha}}\right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{\beta}}-\frac{\partial}{\partial z^{\beta}}\right)\right]\epsilon \\
W *\epsilon &= W\epsilon + \epsilon^{\alpha\beta}\left(\frac{\partial W}{\partial y^{\alpha}}+\frac{\partial W}{\partial z^{\alpha}}\right)\left(\frac{\partial\epsilon}{\partial y^{\beta}}-\frac{\partial\epsilon}{\partial z^{\beta}}\right)
\end{align}
I can go-on, but I don't think I am headed to the right direction. Please help friends and Professors or point me to the right direction.

Comment: Which eqs. in link? The notation seems different. What are the definitions of $d$ and $d_x$?

Comment: Equation (2.24) is the Vasiliev field equation. I am trying to show that it is invariant under the first part of (2.23) transformations. I am using W instead of U. Apologies for the confusion. 
\begin{equation} 
d = d_{x }+ d_{z} , \quad  d_{z} = dz^{\alpha}\frac{\partial}{\partial z^{\alpha}}
 \end{equation}

Comment: $d_{x}$ is an ordinary spacetime derivative in my understanding.

Comment: Your starting equation seems wrong already. Invariance under local Lorentz reads $0 = \delta ( d_x W + W \star W ) = d_x \delta W + \delta W \star W + W \star \delta W$. This doesn't seem to be what you have at the start.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Prahar... I stumbled on the star product: 
\begin{equation} 
\delta (d_{x}) = d_{x}(\delta W) = 0 \\
\delta (W) \star W = \left( d\epsilon + [W, \epsilon] \right) \star W
\end{equation}

Comment: Continuing on above expressions
\begin{equation} 
\delta (d_{x}) = d_{x} (\delta W) = d_{x} \left( d\epsilon + [W, \epsilon] \right)= 0 +  d_{x}[W, \epsilon] \\

\left( d\epsilon + [W, \epsilon] \right)  \star W = d\epsilon \star W + [W, \epsilon] \star W
\end{equation}
 Is it obvious to you which of these star products collapse to zero, if any?